# Nome lista non definito

Tags: python

When I run this code, I get the error "NameError: name 'w' is not defined"

```
q = open("programma", "r")
q = q.read()
time.sleep(0.5)
print("estrapolazione programma")
a = -1
s = 0
w = [""]
par = [""]
for s in q:
  a += 1
  if q[a] == ".":
    s = w
    par.append("".join(s))
    del w
  else:
    w.append(q[a])
print(par)
```

I don't understand why it tells me `w` is not defined in `w.append(q[a])`, when it is defined 9 lines above.

Comment: Instead of `del w` use `w = [""]`

Comment: Eng: Your problem is the `del w`, which undefines `w`. At the next loop iteration `w` is undefined. It (original language of the question before editing): Quando esegui `del w`, rimuovi la definizione di `w`. Alla iterazione successiva, se entri nell'`else`, `w` non é definito (e quindi l'errore). PS: Su StackOverflow é obbligatorio usare l'inglese (altrimenti le domande/risposte vengono eliminate)

Comment: thanks, I thought del del would delete the list in the senzo that removed all the elements inside.

Comment: @GPhilo You should have changed the title as well

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes, I tried, but the closest translation is already taken as a title and I'm not quite sure how to adapt it, so I thought I'd leave it as it is.

Answer (score 3):

Because you `del w` in one of the branches, that deletes the variable itself so if that branch is taken on any iteration which is not the last, the next iteration will break either by trying to `w.append` on a `w` which is has been un-defined, or because you try to `del w` *again*.

Half the program doesn't make sense really, you're iterating on `q` but then you're not using the result, and in instead you're assigning `w` to `s` (your iteration variable) before deleting the former?

- `s` is the same as `q[a]`, so you don't need `a`, just use `s` directly, and you don't generally need to initialise the loop variable, nor should you usually asign to it
- if you want to clear `w`, do that, literally, you can use `w.clear()`, or `del w[:]`
- alternatively you can assign a new empty list to it `w = []`, doesn't matter here but there are cases where it does
- incidentally I don't see the point of initialising `w` to a list containing an empty string, since you're joining on an empty string `"".join([])` and `"".join([''])` have the same result and you're never testing if it's empty
- though it doesn't really matter here it's also good practice to close files after using them, and when using "text mode" file IO to specify the encoding explicitly

Here's with a few cleanups:

```py
with open('programma', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    contents = f.read()

time.sleep(0.5)
print("estrapolazione programma")

word = []
par = []
for char in contents:
    if char == '.':
        par.append(''.join(word))
        word = [] # or w.clear()
    else:
        word.append(char)
print(par)
```

Incidentally, as-is the entire thing can be written

```py
par = contents.split('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the list `w` instead of `del w` you can use `w.clear()`

`del w` deletes the list and you have to create new instance of list to use it. where as `w.clear()` clears the list but does not delete the list and it can be used again